# Different GNU ABI Tag for same C library version?

Tags: linux, gcc, glibc, elf, abi

I have two ELF binaries on my Linux machine. When I run `file` on them I receive the following:

`File#1: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.2.0, not stripped`

`File#2: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, stripped`

Now as far as I understand it, the `for GNU/Linux 2.2.X` part stems from the `.note.ABI-tag` section of the binary and is added by the linker. The resulting value of `2.2.X` depends on the version of the C library that is linked to the binary and describes the lowest ABI version that this C library version supports - meaning that File #1 will be supported on machines with a Linux kernel >= 2.2.0 and File #2 on machines with a Linux kernel >= 2.2.5. (Is that correct, or am I already wrong here?)

I would suppose that the differences in the ABI tag would stem from two different C library versions contained in the two binaries. But when I examine the strings of the binaries, both of them contain the string `glibc 2.3.2`.

How is this possible? It seems unreasonable to me, that a patch of some sort to the GNU C Library which didn't result in a version number change would change the supported ABI version...

Comment: Just guessing (not being savvy with the intricacies of libc versioning), but perhaps the version given by `file` depends on the actual functions being used by the executables; i.e. the first executable uses functions that last changed in v2.2.0, while the second executable uses some function that has been patched in v2.2.5...?

Answer (score 0):

The glibc ABI is supposed to be independent of the kernel version it is built for, and the test suite attempts to verify that a newly built glibc conforms to the official ABI.

The minimum kernel version required by a glibc release can be specified at glibc configure time, and this is what ends up in the `.note.ABI-tag` section.  No patching of the glibc sources is needed.  I'm not entirely sure whether it is correct that the configured minimum kernel version ends up in dynamically linked binaries (because it should be possible to run the binaries on older kernels with a differently built glibc).

However, for statically linked binaries, this is certainly correct because configuring a higher minimum kernel version will make the program fail to run on older kernels.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what do you think then causes the change in the supported kernel version? Does the linker determine which kernel version is required and if there are other static libraries contained in the binary, these could bump up the minimum kernel version?

Comment: I assume these two binaries were statically linked against different versions of glibc.